# How to prevent a string from entering a double variable and messing up the program

Tags: c++, validation, user-input

Just want to know how to prevent a user from entering bad input like inputting cookies when the variable is a double instead of a string. For example in my code i am using a text file that will be read by my program that will take in all the information from Data.txt and put it into the variables like RecWidth. Is there a way of making a string like cookies from trying to go into RecWidth just result in RecWidth being a 0.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

int main() {
std::ifstream input_file("Data.txt", ios::in);
ofstream out_data("Output.txt", ios::out); 

int age = 0;
int totalAge = 0;
double RecLength, RecWidth, RecArea, RecPerimiter, CirRadius, CirCricumfrence = 0;
double totalWidth = 0;
double totalLength = 0;
double totalPerimiter = 0;
double totalSavings = 0;
double totalArea = 0;
double totalRadius = 0;
double totalCArea = 0;
double totalCircumfrence = 0;
double CirArea, Savings, NumberOfPeople = 0;
string NameFirst, NameLast;

while (!input_file.eof())
{

input_file >> RecLength;
input_file >> RecWidth;
totalLength = totalLength + RecLength;
totalWidth = totalWidth + RecWidth;
RecArea = RecLength * RecWidth;
totalArea = totalArea + RecArea;
RecPerimiter = (RecLength * 2) + (RecWidth * 2);
totalPerimiter = totalPerimiter + RecPerimiter;

input_file >> CirRadius;
totalRadius = totalRadius + CirRadius;
CirCricumfrence =  2 * M_PI * CirRadius;
totalCircumfrence = totalCircumfrence + CirCricumfrence;
CirArea = M_PI * pow(CirRadius, 2.0);
totalCArea = totalCArea + CirArea;

input_file >> NameFirst; 
input_file >> NameLast;
NumberOfPeople++;
input_file>> age;
totalAge = totalAge + age; 
input_file>> Savings;
totalSavings = totalSavings + Savings;

} 

out_data << "Rectangle:" << endl << "The total lengths= " << totalLength << ", width= " << totalWidth << ", area= " << totalArea << ", perimeter= " << totalPerimiter << endl << endl;
out_data << "Circle:" << endl << "The total Radius= " << totalRadius << ", area= " << CirArea << ", circumfrence= " << CirCricumfrence << endl << endl;
out_data << "Person:" << endl << "Total number of persons= " << NumberOfPeople << endl << "Total age= " << totalAge << endl << "The total saving= " << totalSavings << endl << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should post this question in threat-modelling section.

Comment: You should post this question in threat-modelling section.

Comment: I think you could edit your question and to do it more concise. Basically, as I understand you want to validate that the input data type matches with the declared type

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to check if the [>> operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) was successful or not - in case it wasn't you should assign the variable in question to `0`. Consider this code:

```
input_file >> RecLength;
if (input_file.fail()) {
  RecLength = 0.0;
  input_file.clear();
}
```

It will first try to read a `double` from `input_file` - if it fails the [failbit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/) will be set and we're checking this flag after the operation - to assign the variable to `0.0` in case something went wrong (and finally reset the failbit for the next operation).

The following code adds these necessary checks for the failbit and will prevent surprising values:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
using namespace std;

int main() {
  std::ifstream input_file("Data.txt", ios::in);
  ofstream out_data("Output.txt", ios::out);
  int age = 0, totalAge = 0;
  double RecLength, RecWidth, RecArea, RecPerimiter, CirRadius, CirCricumfrence = 0;
  double totalWidth = 0, totalLength = 0, totalPerimiter = 0, totalSavings = 0;
  double totalArea = 0, totalRadius = 0, totalCArea = 0, totalCircumfrence = 0, CirArea, Savings, NumberOfPeople = 0;
  string NameFirst, NameLast;
  while (!input_file.eof())
  {
    input_file >> RecLength;
    if (input_file.fail()) {
      RecLength = 0.0;
      input_file.clear();
    }

    input_file >> RecWidth;
    if (input_file.fail()) {
      RecWidth = 0.0;
      input_file.clear();
    }
    totalLength = totalLength + RecLength;
    totalWidth = totalWidth + RecWidth;
    RecArea = RecLength * RecWidth;
    totalArea = totalArea + RecArea;
    RecPerimiter = (RecLength * 2) + (RecWidth * 2);
    totalPerimiter = totalPerimiter + RecPerimiter;

    input_file >> CirRadius;
    if (input_file.fail()) {
      CirRadius = 0.0;
      input_file.clear();
    }
    totalRadius = totalRadius + CirRadius;
    CirCricumfrence = 2 * M_PI * CirRadius;
    totalCircumfrence = totalCircumfrence + CirCricumfrence;
    CirArea = M_PI * pow(CirRadius, 2.0);
    totalCArea = totalCArea + CirArea;

    input_file >> NameFirst;
    input_file >> NameLast;
    NumberOfPeople++;

    input_file >> age;
    if (input_file.fail()) {
      age = 0;
      input_file.clear();
    }
    totalAge = totalAge + age;

    input_file >> Savings;
    if (input_file.fail()) {
      Savings = 0.0;
      input_file.clear();
    }
    totalSavings = totalSavings + Savings;
  }
  out_data << "Rectangle:" << endl << "The total lengths= " << totalLength << ", width= " << totalWidth << ", area= " << totalArea << ", perimeter= " << totalPerimiter << endl << endl;
  out_data << "Circle:" << endl << "The total Radius= " << totalRadius << ", area= " << CirArea << ", circumfrence= " << CirCricumfrence << endl << endl;
  out_data << "Person:" << endl << "Total number of persons= " << NumberOfPeople << endl << "Total age= " << totalAge << endl << "The total saving= " << totalSavings << endl << endl;
  return 0;
}
```